# Meu projeto aspNet core 3.0 não acessa as DLL gerada pelo visual basic

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, dll

*Recebi uma dll gerada em vb6 para integrar com minha api em asp.net Core, nessa dll à diversos métodos de cálculos.*

*Com isso, eu devo invocar esses métodos da dll em meu projeto asp.net core 3.0 no visual studio.*

*É possível importar a dll para o meu projeto asp.net core normalmente, e ate invocar os métodos. Ao iniciar meu projeto asp.net tudo funciona normalmente, ate o momento de informar os parâmetros solicitados para que o método dentro da dll seja invocado*

*Na linha em que meu projeto em asp.Net core instancia minha DLL, o seguinte ero é mostrado mostra o seguinte erro...*

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C0131351-6182-46C9-87E0-A509400E50AD} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Classe não registrada (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

*Dentro de csproj, minha dll está referenciada da seguinte maneira como mostra no xml*

```
<ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="CSGlobal.dll">
      <Guid>9ddd0edf-9e32-48b0-ae31-5beb13a85606</Guid>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: registrou ela no gac? Você não está tentando executar uma DLL gerada pra 32 bits num runtime de 64?

Comment: registrei ela usando RegSvr32, vi que no asp.net o meio de registrar é pelo regasm, porem, se eu regitrar ela diretamente com regasm me retorna um erro  RegAsm : error RA0000 : Falha ao carregar 'C:\CSGlobal.dll' porque não é um assembly .NET válido

Comment: não seria com o gacutil -i nome.dll ?

Comment: com gacutil deu o seguinte erro Failure adding assembly to the cache:   O módulo deveria conter um manifesto de assembly.

Comment: No Gerenciados de configurações a plataforma esta setada para Any CPU